# Check promise object for null state before destructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

```
Function().then(
  ({
    property1, property2, property3,
  }) => {
    // do stuff 
    }
  },
)
```

What I've tried

```
//optional chain
Function()?.then(

//still not sure why this doesn't work
```

My issue is I will get an error saying
Cannot destructure property 'property1' of 'object null' as it is null

how can I check the object null state in .then() to avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no way that "optional chaining" cannot work since that would mean that the value returned by the function is "null" or "undefined", but we know for sure that it returns always a Promise which is an object.

Comment: @Xion14 thanks for that. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure after a check, within a .then callback function

```
Function().then(
    (result) => {
     //guard clause to check if result is null
     if(!result) return
    const { property1, property2, property3} = result
  // do stuff 

  }
)
```

Comment: elegant defensive check